# Videos and Images with proper extension

Tags: bash, shell-script, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently imported my pictures (and videos) from iPhone to Windows 10. For some strange reason, a lot of the images and videos had their file extensions switched. i.e. 2022_001.mov is actually an image or 2022_002.jpg is actually a video. It was quite random and universally not the case. Since I am on Windows, I couldn't really use these files until the extensions were fixed.

I have WSL on this system. Is there a way I can fix this and rename the files correctly? Maybe through a bash script?

I have written a script which I will post as an answer below but there may be better ways.

Comment: wouldn't be a better place github or gitlab for saving code

Comment: I think you should instead look into how the images are being imported that causes the suffix to change. It is not normal for a filename to become altered through a simple transfer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but as Kamil explained, everything posted here has to be either a question or an answer to a question. Also, this is a really very specific situation that only deals with exactly two very limited cases: i) files with a capital `JPG` extension that should instead have a `mov` extension and files with a capital `MOV` extension that should instead have a lower case `jpg` one. As such, it is unlikely to help future visitors since your situation seems to be very particular.

Comment: @terdon, maybe my situation is unique but I find it hard to believe. I am just plugging an iPhone into windows 10 and letting windows import all the pictures and videos. To me it sounds like a bug either on Apple side or Microsoft. My hope in posting this question was three folds. 1) Others should know that something like this could happen to them. 2) There is a potential fix 3) Someone else can look at this and say - "there's actually a much better way to handle this".

Comment: @DrPhil that does make sense yes, thank you for explaining. I had assumed it was a one-off weird glitch. Now, we have some weird rules here about posting (and we are not very good at explaining them, sorry), and one of them is that all questions need to be actual questions and not a combination of questions or answers. I have now edited your question to remove the answer and make it ask something. it would be great if you could post your script as an answer! (You can still see it in the question's [history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/696025/revisions)).

Answer (score 0):

### I ended up writing this script that solved my issue.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

for file in ./*
do
fileName=$(basename -- "$file")
fileName="${fileName%.*}"
ext="${file##*.}"
fileType=$(file "$file")
  if [[ $ext == "JPG" ]]; then
    if echo "$fileType" | grep -q "Apple QuickTime"; then
      mv "$file" "$fileName.mov"
    fi
  fi
  if [[ $ext == "MOV" ]]; then
    if echo "$fileType" | grep -q "JPEG"; then
      mv "$file" "$fileName.jpg"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: If you have a .mov and a .jpeg file with the same basename, then this isn't going to work.

Comment: Instead of fileType=$(file "$file"), try fileType=$(mimetype -b "$file")